# Remove same property value duplicate from array of objects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the below array

```
const values = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    age: 12
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    age: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'A',
    age: 31
  }
]
```

and I want using lodash remove an object from this array that has the same name, so it should return:

```
 const values = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    age: 12
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    age: 1
  }
]
```

Using

```
_.uniqWith(_.isEqual, values)
```

only remove duplicate if the whole object is duplicated ...
How can I remove using property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.uniqBy()` the `name` property instead:

```js
const values = [{"name":"A","age":12},{"name":"B","age":1},{"name":"A","age":31}]

const result = _.uniqBy(values, 'name')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```